# cannot PRINT the highest number and lowest number that are inputed into VB

Tags: vb.net

My question is about trying to PRINT the numbers that are inputed by the user, but it always PRINTS out 0 0 0 for Maxno and Minno. This is all I've tried, hope I can get any  help. I'm not sure on how to improve it so I came here to find some help.

```
Imports System

Public Module Module1

Public Sub Main()
    Const MSG_ENTRYNAME = "Please enter the name of the student."
    Const MSG_ERROR = "Score not valid, please enter again."
    Const MSG_ENTRYDATA = "Please enter the score of the respective student."
    Dim marks(10) as Decimal
    Dim name(10) as STRING
    Dim sum as Decimal
    Dim count as INTEGER
    Dim mean as INTEGER
    Dim maxNo as Decimal
    Dim minNo as Decimal
    Dim maxcount as INTEGER
    Dim mincount as INTEGER
    Dim maxName as STRING
    Dim minName as STRING
    Dim maxIndex as INTEGER
    Dim minIndex as INTEGER
    for i = 0 To 2
        Console.WriteLine(MSG_ENTRYNAME)
        name(i) = Console.ReadLine
        Console.WriteLine(MSG_ENTRYDATA)
        marks(i) = Console.ReadLine
        while marks(i) < 25 or marks(i) > 100
            Console.WriteLine(MSG_ERROR)
            Marks(i) = Console.Readline
        end while
    next

    for i = 0 to marks.Length - 1
        if marks(i) > maxNo then
            marks(i) = maxNo
        end if

        minNo = marks(i)
        if marks(i) < minNO then
            minNo = marks(i)
        end if

        sum = +marks(i)
    next

    Console.WriteLine(MaxNo)
    Console.WriteLine(MinNo)
    Console.WriteLine(sum)
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: You need to debug your code. If you don't know how, now is the time to learn. You set a breakpoint at the top of the code and step through it line by line, checking the state at each step. As soon as the actual state differs from your expectation, you've found an issue and can investigate that specifically. You don't fix errors simply by reading code in the vast majority of cases.

Answer (score 0):

You code has some simple logic errors. Please check the fixed code below.

```
minNo = marks(i)                    'added 
For i = 0 to 2                      'changed
    If marks(i) > maxNo Then
        maxNo = marks(i)             'changed
    End If

    'minNo = marks(i)                'removed
    If marks(i) < minNo Then
        minNo = marks(i)
    End If

    sum += marks(i)                   'changed
Next
```